# HP web tours sample application login for Loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

I have installed LoadRunner 12.01 Community Edition and I am following the tutorial provided to me. For this, I am trying to access HP Web tours application which am able to access at
localhost port 1080 (web tours apache server is running). I have been trying to login using usernames/passwords as jojo/bean , joe/young but couldn't. I also tried to signup for a new account but looks like all usernames have already been taken. Please help. I want to learn more about it and I am stuck.

Comment: Are you using jojo as the username and bean as the password?

Comment: Yes I am using jojo as username and bean as password

Comment: strange, this is the first time I encounter someone with this issue.

Comment: I asked the team and someone actually encountered this before... see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

(I assume you already tried restarting the machine and the server)

This can happen if your Perl installation thinks that the the line endings of your .pl files are in Linux format when in reality they are in Windows format.

What you can do is the following:

1) Find the user file for jojo (it is in \WebTours\cgi-bin\users\jojo)

2) Edit the file with notepad++

3) In notepad++ do Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Unix format

4) Save the file and restart the server

Good Luck,
Boris

Answer (score 0):

The file WebTours\cgi-bin\users\jojo  does not allow logins even after EOL - unix format including mult variations  ... the first bean is on a separate line ...then Jojo;Bean   then below three lines ;

bean
Jojo;Bean

;

Answer (score 0):

... Used Firefox .. NOT IE 11 and got better URL links to show - http://127.0.0.1:1080/WebTours/    Got an Admin page and new user registration page to display. I then added new user from the registration page which that newly created user is working.

Comment: Are you suggesting that this is an IE 11 only problem?